# c# При обработке json возвращает null

Tags: c#, json

При парсинге json словарь всегда имеет null значение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```
 public static Dictionary<string, Data> GetNumberPrice(string Service)
        {
            string response = @"""{\""tg\"":{\""44\"":{\""count\"":31,\""price\"":\""50.00\"",\""retail_price\"":75},\""49\"":{\""count\"":120,\""price\"":\""50.00\"",\""retail_price\"":75},\""78\"":{\""count\"":24,\""price\"":\""150.00\"",\""retail_price\"":225}}}""";
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response).ToString();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelPrice>(jsonResult);
            Dictionary<string, Data> keyValues = result.Get;
            return keyValues;
        }
    }
}
public class ModelPrice
{
    public Dictionary<string, Data> Get { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public string count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public string price { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("retail_price")]
    public long retail_price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 1. Экранирование странное, много лишнего, не? 2. Зачем два раза десериализация? 3. Где вы увидели в JSON словарь с именем `Get`? Я лично вижу словарь с именем `tg`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я лично вижу словарь с именем tg --- понял ошибку, не знал что это влияет на парсинг json. Экранирование от сайта такое, прикрепил как есть

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Я лично вижу словарь с именем tg, а если имен словарей может быть сотня, есть какой то универсальный подход?

Comment: @ИванРудаков _Экранирование от сайта такое_ - в отладчике чтоли смотрели? :) В дебаг или консоль выводите. Отладчик визуально эскейп-символы добавляет для более удобного просмотра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ModelPrice
{
    [JsonProperty("tg")]
    public Dictionary<string, Data> Tg { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public string Count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("retail_price")]
    public long RetailPrice { get; set; }
}
```

```
public static Dictionary<string, Data> GetNumberPrice(string Service)
{
    string response = @"""{""tg"":{""44"":{""count"":31,""price"":""50.00"",""retail_price"":75},""49"":{""count"":120,""price"":""50.00"",""retail_price"":75},""78"":{""count"":24,""price"":""150.00"",""retail_price"":225}}}""";
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelPrice>(response).Tg;
}
```

---

Если `tg` тоже свойство, которое неизвестно на этапе компиляции, то можно выбросить `ModelPrice` и сделать вот так

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Data>>(response)["tg"];
```

Строчку можете передавать в рантайме методу, ну или если первый элемент - всегда то что нужно, тогда вот так.

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Data>>(response).Values.First();
```

Comment: экранирование да в отладчике от студии смотрел, в консоль не выводил ибо тогда отличаться данные будут)

Comment: @ИванРудаков слезайте вы уже с JSON.NET на нормальный `System.Text.Json` :)

Comment: код с ответа тот что нужно, с таким экранирование хорошо работает так

Comment: public static Dictionary<string, Data> GetNumberPrice(string Service)
        {
            string response = @"""{\""tg\"":{\""44\"":{\""count\"":31,\""price\"":\""50.00\"",\""retail_price\"":75},\""49\"":{\""count\"":120,\""price\"":\""50.00\"",\""retail_price\"":75},\""78\"":{\""count\"":24,\""price\"":\""150.00\"",\""retail_price\"":225}}}""";
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response).ToString();
            var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Data>>>(jsonResult);
            return res[Service];
        }

Comment: System.Text.Json надо почитать) Привык что NewJsonSoft по старинке около 50% все используют и я в том числе XD

Comment: @ИванРудаков для простых задач почти одно и то же. Последний только уже встроен в .NET, его не надо устанавливать

Comment: @ИванРудаков конкретно для вашей всего 2 изменения `[JsonPorpertyName("...")]` и `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<...>(...)`

Comment: .Net это хорошо) Но сейчас пишу библиотеку на Net.Framework для удобства использования на обоих типов проекта)

Comment: @ИванРудаков а смысл? Под фреймворк пишут только легаси-проекты, точнее переписывают и дописывают. Смысла создавать на нем что-то новое отпал больше года назад с выходом .NET 5.

Comment: @ИванРудаков вот смотрите, я что-то пишу, мне потребовалась ваша библиотека, ставлю, а она за собой вагон с прицепом JSON.NET тащит увеличивая вес моего проекта в 2 раза, зачем оно мне? :)

Comment: это знаю, сам на net.core 6 часто пишу, но бывает и на framework пишу где 40% проектов. Так что пока полностью с него не ушел, то можно библиотеки и под него делать также ) И простым проектам отдаю предпочтение framework из за простоты

Comment: а она за собой вагон с прицепом JSON.NET тоже верно) подумаю над этим) Кстати верно подметили, замечал много раз ставишь библиотеку и прицепом еще идут XD если бы не Json, то хватило бы средств штатных ибо регуляркой не смог распарсить, типизация json монотонная, привязок мало)